# get data out of room database to from a livedata object

Tags: android, android-room, android-livedata

Good day,

I need some help with LiveData and Room database. The idea I have is that I want to allow the user to backup the contents of a Room database with a click of the button, which will then save the contents of the database as JSON file.

The issue I have is the following:

I want to get the data out of the database when the user clicks the button to backup the database. My app is structured like this:

***Dao***

```
@Query("SELECT * FROM media")
LiveData<List<Media>> getAll();
```

***Repository***

```
private final MediaDao mMediaDao;
public LiveData<List<Media>> getListOfMedia() {
    return mMediaDao.getAll();
}
```

***ViewModel***

```
public LiveData<List<Media>> getMedia() {
    return mMediaRepository.getListOfMedia();
}
```

Normally what I would do is observe the LiveData on the Fragment and any changes will then get me the data from the live data object. Thing is the data doesnt "change" per say.

So how can I get the data out of the Livedata object when the user clicks the button?

Comment: change `LiveData<List<Media>> getAll();` to `List<Media> getAll();`

Comment: Its not the most idea solution, is there not a better way to do this without having to remove LiveData?

Comment: so do need to observe your backup data changes?

Comment: no i dont, i just feel this is a dirty way of avoiding LiveData

Comment: dont make your life harder if you dont have to: https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/room/accessing-data.html#query-simple

Answer (score 4):

This might be a bit late, but you can create numerous query methods for the same dataset.

For example, I have two methods fetching the same data, one returning a `LiveData<List<Media>>` object, and one returning `List<Media>`, like so:

```
@Query("SELECT * FROM media")
LiveData<List<Media>> getLiveAll();

@Query("SELECT * FROM media")
List<Media> getAll();
```